# Identify point information OpenLayers works GeoExplorer not

Tags: boundless-suite

I am using the OpenGeo Suite. I can preview a layer in the GeoServer OpenLayers view, I can click on points and see the data from a layer produced from a PostGIS view. However when I do this in GeoExplorer I click and nothing happens. But if I click on a standard layer produced from a table (happens to contain the same geom data, just different fields) I can identify the point data.

I should say, I click the point, and in Firefox it brings up the little load icon, but that then disappears.

**Update**
I have narrowed down the issue to be with views with a where statement that limits records that are only a certain species. Without this where clause the layer allows me to click. Going to try make the view using GeoServer rather than PostgreSQL directly.

**Update 2**
The above did not work with the GeoServer query. See my SQL below, the issue comes when I place the last where clause. The layer still loads and I can see the points, in GeoExploer + OpenLayers, but I can only click and identify points in the OpenLayers example.

```
SELECT 
 taxom_tbl.scientificname, 
 sheet_tbl.eventtime, 
 sheet_tbl.eventdate, 
 sites_tbl.the_geom, 
 sites_tbl.sitename, 
 rivers_tbl.rivername, 
 rmi_group_tbl.rmigroupname, 
 record_tbl.category_of_taxom, 
 record_tbl.number_of_taxom
FROM 
 public.taxom_tbl, 
 public.sites_tbl, 
 public.sheet_tbl, 
 public.rmi_group_tbl, 
 public.rivers_tbl, 
 public.record_tbl
WHERE 
taxom_tbl.taxom_id = record_tbl.taxom_id AND
sites_tbl.site_id = sheet_tbl.site_id AND
rmi_group_tbl.group_id = sites_tbl.group_id AND
rivers_tbl.river_id = sites_tbl.river_id AND
record_tbl.sheet_id = sheet_tbl.sheet_id AND
taxom_tbl.scientificname = 'Cased caddisfly'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check your query doesn't have ; at the end. I know when i use pgAdmin3 it places ; if i use the graphical query builder. I had the same issue you describe, and removing that fixed my issue. Only figured it when I decided to write the SQL by hand over the builder.